# reading xml file for loading image thumbnails in html

Tags: html, xml, image

I'm working on my website and have image galleries in multiple pages. I am trying to create a single XML that lists all the images. I want to use this xml file to load images in the various HTML pages as per the categories. I have created the XML file as shown below but not sure how to read this in HTML. I know basics of HTML and this is my first attempt at combining XML with HTML.

This is the XML file I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<image_gallery>
<music>
 <image href="path to image" alt="description"/>
</music>
<landscapes>
...
</landscapes>
```

I want the output to look like this in the HTML file:

```
<img src="path to image" alt="description" />
<img src="path to image" alt="description" />
<img src="path to image" alt="description" />
<img src="path to image" alt="description" />
<img src="path to image" alt="description" />
```

How do I do this? I've gone through some google search results but don't really understand much of it because the answers are not quite specific and there are multiple ways listed.

I tried the following and it didn't work

```
<xsl:for-each select="image_gallery/music">
<xsl:value-of select="image"/>  
</xsl:for-each>
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp You're probably gonna have to use either javascript or php.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery to call the xml which must be on the same domain and then simply parse the xml and find the images then iterate through them with $.each and display the images. checkout the following:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/